# Corregir datos que devuelve stored procedure - SQLServer 2014

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure

Buenas noches, 
Tengo un stored procedure que me devuelve, según un determinado hotel y un determinado rango de fechas, la cantidad de habitaciones ocupadas y la cantidad de habitaciones libres.
El problema es que me devuelve mal la cantidad de habitaciones libres. Les dejo el código y una imagen con el resultado que obtengo:

```
declare @Fecha_Reserva_Desde date = '20170601'
declare @Fecha_Reserva_Hasta date = '20170603'

SELECT Ho.Descripcion as Hotel, O.Fecha, C.Decripcion, SUM(Cantidad_ocupantes) as 'Habitaciones ocupadas',
(select COUNT(Cantidad_ocupantes) from Ocupacion where Cantidad_ocupantes=0) as 'Habitaciones Libres' 
FROM OCUPACION AS O
INNER JOIN HABITACIONES AS H
    ON (O.Codigo_habitacion = H.Codigo_habitacion)
INNER JOIN HOTELES AS Ho
    ON (H.Codigo_hotel = Ho.Codigo_hotel)
INNER JOIN CATEGORIAS AS C
    ON (C.Codigo_categoria = H.Codigo_categoria)
WHERE O.Fecha BETWEEN @Fecha_Reserva_Desde and @Fecha_Reserva_Hasta 
GROUP BY Ho.Descripcion, O.Fecha, C.Decripcion
ORDER BY Ho.Descripcion;
```

Obtuve lo siguiente:  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La columna 'Habitaciones Libres' me debería dar "17400" donde no haya ocupación, y donde hay 1 ocupación me debería dar 17399.
Desde ya les agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Si se puede poner un ejemplo de los datos en el DB seria mas facil ayudar. La cantidad de Habitaciones se parece muy alto, pero sin ver los datos es imposible saber

Comment: Tengo las tablas:  Hoteles (Codigo_hotel, Descripcion, Codigo_ciudad). Categorías (CodigoCategoria, Descripcion). Ocupacion (Codigo_habitacion, Fecha, Cantidad_ocupantes). Habitaciones (Codigo_habitacion, Codigo_hotel, Nro_habitacion, Codigo_categoria_ Capacidad_maxima). Reservas (Codigo_reserva, Codigo_hotel, Codigo_habitacion, FechaReservaDesde, FechaReservaHasta, Check_in, Check_out, Codigo_persona)

Comment: Pablo, esto `select COUNT(Cantidad_ocupantes) from Ocupacion where Cantidad_ocupantes=0` te suma todos los registros de `Ocupacion` me imagino que al menos debieras filtrar los casos, por fecha hotel, etc. Por otro lado `Cantidad_ocupantes` te da la cantidad de Habitaciones ocupadas? que pasa si hay un matrimonio en una sola habitación?

Comment: Con el select COUNT(Cantidad_ocupantes) from Ocupacion where Cantidad_ocupantes=0, estoy pidiendo que me cuente las habitaciones donde no hay ocupantes, osea que estén libres. Si hay más de una persona en una habitación debería contar como 1 (una) habitación ocupada. Es donde estoy tratando de llegar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Viendo el modelo de datos que agregaste en un comentario (te recuerdo que lo mejor es que lo agregues a la pregunta), veo un poco más claro el tema.

Entiendo que lo que quieres obtener es un listado de la ocupación por fecha categoria y hotel. En base a eso hice algunos cambios a tu coansulta. En primer lugar como no te interesan solo las habitaciones ocupadas sino también las vacías modifique el `FROM` y a `OCUPACION`la accedemos mediante un `LEFT`. Espero te sirva:

```
DECLARE @Fecha_Reserva_Desde DATE = '20170601'
DECLARE @Fecha_Reserva_Hasta DATE = '20170603'

SELECT  Ho.Descripcion as Hotel, 
    O.Fecha, 
    C.Decripcion, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN ISNULL(O.Cantidad_ocupantes,0) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)     as 'Habitaciones ocupadas',
    SUM(CASE WHEN ISNULL(O.Cantidad_ocupantes,0) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)     as 'Habitaciones Libres'
    FROM HABITACIONES AS H
    LEFT JOIN OCUPACION AS O
        ON (O.Codigo_habitacion = H.Codigo_habitacion)
    INNER JOIN HOTELES AS Ho
        ON (H.Codigo_hotel = Ho.Codigo_hotel)
    INNER JOIN CATEGORIAS AS C
        ON (C.Codigo_categoria = H.Codigo_categoria)
    WHERE O.Fecha BETWEEN @Fecha_Reserva_Desde and @Fecha_Reserva_Hasta 
    GROUP BY Ho.Descripcion, O.Fecha, C.Decripcion
    ORDER BY Ho.Descripcion
```

Comment: Genio! me sirvió a la perfección!!!

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que sucede es que no estas dando un identificador a tu segunda consulta, por eso te entrega un valor cualquiera, por ejemplo, y es lo que imagino, debes pasarle un left join en vez de usarlo en el select:

```
SELECT Ho.Descripcion as Hotel, O.Fecha, C.Decripcion, SUM(Cantidad_ocupantes) as 'Habitaciones ocupadas',

IFNULL(Oc.cnt,0) as 'Habitaciones Libres' 

FROM OCUPACION AS O
INNER JOIN HABITACIONES AS H
    ON (O.Codigo_habitacion = H.Codigo_habitacion)
INNER JOIN HOTELES AS Ho
    ON (H.Codigo_hotel = Ho.Codigo_hotel)
INNER JOIN CATEGORIAS AS C
    ON (C.Codigo_categoria = H.Codigo_categoria)
LEFT JOIN
(select identificador,COUNT(Cantidad_ocupantes) AS cnt from Ocupacion where Cantidad_ocupantes = 0 GROUP BY identificador) AS Oc ON H.Codigo_habitacion = Oc.identificador

WHERE O.Fecha BETWEEN @Fecha_Reserva_Desde and @Fecha_Reserva_Hasta 

GROUP BY Ho.Descripcion, O.Fecha, C.Decripcion
ORDER BY Ho.Descripcion;
```

Donde Identificador es como unes el resultado de ocupación con el Row correspondiente (por lo que logro ver sería H.codigo_habitacion).

En todo caso si nos pusieras las tablas de prueba en un SQL con gusto te orientaría un poco mas.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta. Me devuelve exactamente los mismos datos que con el código que ya tengo. Cuando me decís que ponga las tablas de prueba en un SQL a qué te referís?

Comment: De lo que hablo con las tablas de prueba es que exportes las tablas que usas en la consulta y la compartas, así yo la cargo en una base de datos de prueba y simulo tu consulta tratando de llegar al resultado esperado.

Comment: Ok, ahora te las paso

Comment: Te comparto los scripts en un enlace de GoogleDrive [Drive]:(https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B33zklqglIaXQmNORE1TSEJibWM?usp=sharing) avisame si podes descargar los scripts

Answer (score 0):

Los resultados dependerán mucho de **cómo** tengas organizado tu modelo de datos. Del mismo modo, podrás hacer cosas con mayor o menor facilidad de acuerdo a cómo estén organizadas tus tablas.

Yo imaginaría un modelo de datos más o menos así:

- Una tabla `hoteles` en la cual tendría una columna fija llamada `habitaciones`. En dicha columna tendría el total de habitaciones de que dispone el hotel. Sería el campo que usaría para calcular sea el total de habitaciones libres, sea el total de ocupadas.
- Una tabla llamada `reservas` en la que registraría la fecha de entrada, la fecha de salida, el número de la habitación, el id del hotel, la cantidad de personas que ocupa la habitación, etc.

El modelo se podría extender más claro está, teniendo por ejemplo una tabla `habitaciones` donde se indicaría el tipo de habitación, el número, etc.

Aquí te muestro un boceto de modelo, la PROCEDURE como podrás ver admite dos parámetros que serían dos rangos de fecha para buscar habitaciones disponibles y ocupadas.

El código se puede quizá mejorar en muchos aspectos, la idea es mostrar un posible camino de solución.

Espero te sirva.

---

#### `Código:`[`Ver Demo`](http://rextester.com/UIHI47028)

```
-- Procedure que busca habitaciones libres y ocupadas
-- en un rango de fechas
-- Ejemplo de uso:  EXEC verLibres '01.06.2017','03.06.2017';


CREATE PROCEDURE verLibres
    @NewEntrada DATETIME,
    @NewSalida DATETIME
AS
    SELECT hs.hotel_id, hs.hotel_nom, h.libres, h.ocupadas, 
    @NewEntrada as desde, @NewSalida as hasta 
    FROM hoteles hs 
        INNER JOIN 
        (
        SELECT COUNT(*) as ocupadas, (MAX(ht.habitaciones) - COUNT(*)) as libres , MAX(ht.hotel_id) as hotel_id
        FROM reservas AS r
        INNER JOIN hoteles as ht
        ON r.hotel_id = ht.hotel_id
        WHERE
            (@NewEntrada < r.fecha_entrada 
            OR
             @NewEntrada > r.fecha_salida)
            AND
            (@NewSalida < r.fecha_entrada 
            OR
             @NewSalida > r.fecha_salida)
        GROUP BY  ht.hotel_id
        ) 
        AS h ON hs.hotel_id=h.hotel_id
GO


CREATE TABLE  hoteles
 ( 
    hotel_id          INT              NOT NULL  , 
    hotel_nom         VARCHAR(20)          NULL  , 
    habitaciones      INT              NOT NULL  
 );


INSERT INTO hoteles (hotel_id, hotel_nom, habitaciones) 
    VALUES 
            (1,'ISTEA 1',17400),
            (2,'ISTEA 2',17400);


-- Mostrar registros en la tabla hoteles

SELECT * FROM hoteles;



CREATE TABLE  reservas
 ( 
    reserva_id        INT              NOT NULL  , 
    hotel_id          INT              NOT NULL  , 
    habitacion_id     INT              NOT NULL  ,
    ocupantes         INT              NOT NULL  ,
    fecha_entrada     DATETIME         NOT NULL  ,
    fecha_salida      DATETIME         NOT NULL  


 );


INSERT INTO reservas 
    (
    reserva_id, hotel_id, habitacion_id, 
    ocupantes, fecha_entrada, fecha_salida
    ) 
    VALUES 
    (1,1,65,2,'2017-06-01','2017-06-03'),
    (2,1,23,1,'2017-06-01','2017-06-03'),
    (3,1,90,2,'2017-06-01','2017-06-04'),
    (4,2,40,1,'2017-06-01','2017-06-05'),
    (5,2,86,2,'2017-06-01','2017-06-02');

-- Mostrando todas las reservas
SELECT * FROM reservas;


-- Probando la procedure

EXEC verLibres '01.06.2017','03.06.2017';
```

---

#### `Resultados`

```
--Tabla hoteles

hotel_id    hotel_nom   habitaciones
1           ISTEA 1     17400
2           ISTEA 2     17400

--Tabla reservas

reserva_id  hotel_id    habitacion_id   ocupantes   fecha_entrada           fecha_salida
1           1           65                  2       01.06.2017 00:00:00     03.06.2017 00:00:00
2           1           23                  1       01.06.2017 00:00:00     03.06.2017 00:00:00
3           1           90                  2       01.06.2017 00:00:00     04.06.2017 00:00:00
4           2           40                  1       01.06.2017 00:00:00     05.06.2017 00:00:00
5           2           86                  2       01.06.2017 00:00:00     02.06.2017 00:00:00

--Habitaciones libres y disponibles en rango de fechas

hotel_id    hotel_nom   libres  ocupadas    desde                           hasta
1           ISTEA 1     17397       3       06.01.2017 00:00:00             06.03.2017 00:00:00
2           ISTEA 2     17398       2       06.01.2017 00:00:00             06.03.2017 00:00:00
```

Comment: @ACedano gracias por tu respuesta!! ya estoy probando el query